# Expand/drill down indicator that makes report title disappear

Tags: ssrs-2012

[image: SSRS]

Why does this expand indicator exists here? All it does is make the Document: title disappear and reappear. I've looked all over the textbox properties but don'[image]t see anything that would make that show up.

Comment: can you post the report design plz? looks like the title is in the same tablix.

Comment: what is the visibility setting of the textbox `Email` - the column header?

Comment: @BhupeshC - "Show". All the elements in that "Email" column is "Show".

Comment: and what about `Display can be toggled by this report item` ?

Comment: For <<Expr>> the "Display..." is checked marked and points to "Document" as it should be BUT "Email" column the "Display...toggled" is NOT checked marked.   The <<Expr>>  changes when the user changes the parameter drop down.

Comment: Ok, I finally found what the issue was. On the "Expr", text box properties, Visibility, for some reason I had "Display can be toggled by this report item" check off. When I unchecked that box the expand toggle on Email field went away. Thanks again BhupeshC for taking a look and responding. CharlesKSQL